# How to calculate the cardinality of the complement of two countable sets of reals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, real-numbers

> Let $A,B\subseteq\Bbb R$ be countable sets. Denote by $A'$ and $B'$ the complements (in $\Bbb R$) of $A$ and $B$ respectively.
>
> What is the cardinality of $C=A'\cap B'$?

I cant figure this one out, it seems that it depends on $A$ and $B$ because if their complement sets won't intersect then I've got empty set. Otherwise I should have countable set I guess.

Comment: Try to ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** Use DeMorgan law to calculate $A'\cap B'$, and remember that the union of two countable sets is countable.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But i cant understand how should complementary set of countable subset of real numbers should look like.

Comment: Why do you need to understand how it looks like?

Comment: $C=A'\capB'$ = $(A\cupB)'$
I can see that if A and B are countable sets CardA=aleph0=CardB.
Union of countable sets gives countable set.
If i am not wrong then the complementary set of this union should give Aleph, complementary in relation to $R$ numbers.

Comment: Admittedly, I am not quite sure what you mean. If you know that $C=(A\cup B)'$, and that $A\cup B$ is countable, then you know that its complement is co-countable. Now, whether or not you know that a co-countable subset of $\Bbb R$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$ is a whole other story.